# Total Column of grouped rows in SSRS Report Builder

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a grouped matrix that has customer drilldown total dollar amounts for every month. Each month is in a column, by customer row. I need to have a grand total for the year by customer on the far right that adds up the monthly charges by customer for the entire year.  I can't figure out how to do this because when I try to add a Total Column to the right of Months it will only add inside the group so what I get is a column Total AFTER each month. I only want a year grand total at the very end.
Thoughts much appreciated.Thanks!

Comment: I can't figure out how to format anything here when I ask a question. But basically if you look at the table at this post. I want to know how much each of his projects cost for the .... 
year.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24193954/how-to-sum-ssrs-matrix-columns-on-row-group

Comment: For your reference https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting

Comment: If my answer sorted you out, can you please click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. :)

Comment: I did back in June and it won't let me again

Comment: It should appear as a green check mark like this one. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48430690/prorate-a-monthly-charge-to-daily-for-a-partial-month

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a total column by selecting the matrix then in the `Column Groups` section at the bottom right-click the column group | `Add Total` | `After` | like in the example below. Then add the expression in the new column.

```
=Sum(Fields!total_amount.Value)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly! I can't believe I couldn't find that in any online tutorial or You Tube video or the extensive help doc in Report Builder!

Comment: No worries mate, glad I could help